# catkin_make vs catkin_make_isolated, which is preferred?

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, build, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

During our recent work on the ROS Visual Studio Code plugin (https://github.com/ajshort/vscode-ros, we're still working on a fork), we have noticed that the plugin is assuming the workspace to have been built with `catkin_make` instead of `catkin_make_isolated` since `devel` is being searched instead of `devel_isolated`.

Is there a preferred choice between `catkin_make` and `catkin_make_isolated`?

The only [*official* documentation](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0134.html) does not seem to imply any preference and it seems quite a few people are still using `catkin_make` over `catkin_make_isolated`. Some differences I have noticed:

- `catkin_make_isolated` generates a `.catkin_workspace` file while `catkin_make` does not
- `catkin_make_isolated` has `--install` enabled by default
- `catkin_make_isolated` allows building non-catkin packages? (not sure if there is any actual example of this)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320613/catkin_make-vs-catkin_make_isolated,-which-is-preferred?/) by [kejxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40781/kejxu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-04-08

Post score: 7

Answer (score 2):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a "normal" developer I would describe the options like this:

- `catkin_make` was the first script around to build catkin workspace and is therefore used in many tutorials. It has several down sides (requiring non-standard logic in packages to declared cross-package target dependencies) and limitation (can't process plain CMake packages, requires all targets across all packages in a workspace to be unique). Therefore I wouldn't recommend to use it.
- `catkin_make_isolated` is the script which was developed next which addresses all these shortcomings. It comes at the cost of being slower since it processes all packages sequentially. It is being used on build.ros.org in the devel and PR jobs. I would recommend using this if you want the most reliable solution (exclusively for ROS 1).
- `catkin_tools` (called `catkin build` above) is similar to `catkin_make_isolated` but addresses the performance limitation by processing packages in parallel where possible. It also has a lot of usability features which makes it much easier to use and configure. On the downside this tool is not being actively maintained for the past years so I wouldn't recommend it either.
- `colcon` is the new build tool developed for ROS 2 and works similar to `catkin_tools` with less usability features at the moment but being able to build any kind of packages (catkin, ament, CMake, Python setuptools, gradle, bazel, cargo, ...) on all major platforms (Linux, macOS, Windows). While developed for ROS 2 it in principle also works for ROS 1. If you are willing to use something more bleeding edge (which might come with quirks which haven't been resolved / polished yet) this might be an option. The big advantage is that the tool is very modular and actively developed and extended by multiple parties.

Since you are writing an extension for VSCode I would argue that `colcon` would be the best option - why?

- It is the only tool actively being maintained. And if you want to contribute your patches will likely be reviewed, merged and released in a timely manner.
- It is highly module and configurable which will allow you to provide various options difficult to implement with the other tools.
- Your extension would support ROS 1 as well as ROS 2.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kejxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40781/kejxu/) on 2019-04-09**:
very informative, good to know! I would need to take a look at `colcon` first in this case, thanks =)

**Comment by [boxer911](https://answers.ros.org/users/50666/boxer911/) on 2020-02-26**:
When you use 'catkin_make_isolated' should you continue you doing so from that point? Do you still build packages from source in src folder and cd back to catkin_ws then run 'catkin_make_isolated'?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I prefer `catkin_make` unless I'm in a workspace that requires `catking_make_isolated` (yes, because it can build plain-cmake packages).

- `catkin_make` treats the entire workspace as a single cmake project, and builds it with a single invocation of cmake. Since `catkin_make` treats the entire workspace as a single package, it's faster for incremental builds that only change code, but slower when you need to regenerate the build files, and more sensitive to dependency issues between packages.
- `catkin_make_isolated` treats each package as a separate cmake project, and builds and installs each separately, in dependency order. This is why it's able to build plain cmake packages.
- The catkin tools project (`catkin build`) also treats each package as a separate cmake project and builds each one separately (I'm not sure if it does the install step or not). It's an evolution of `catkin_make_isolated`, but with more features and a more thoughtful design. `catkin build` isn't as sensitive to dependency issues as `catkin_make`, so it's become quite popular in the past few years. I think it's about as fast as `catkin_make` but I don't use it enough to compare.

I'm not sure how all of those will mesh with VSCode, but hopefully that gives your a better idea of what they're doing and why.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2019-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kejxu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40781/kejxu/) on 2019-04-08**:
Thanks Austin! As of today, our plan for integration would only go as far as using VSCode just like a normal command prompt.

I have recently just started working a bit with `catkin_make`, and have never heard about/tried `catkin build`. Thanks for pointing those out, I will go take a look =)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-09**:
@ahendrix wrote:

> `catkin build` isn't as sensitive to dependency issues as `catkin_make`

interesting observation. I would actually think it'd be the opposite (because `catkin_make` coalesces all projects into one big one, it works with slightly incorrect `CMakeLists.txt`, whereas those will fail with `catkin_tools`).